# Execute in every 5 minutes with Chime Scheduler

Tags: scheduler, vert.x

I am new to vertx. My application needs a scheduler which checks for the status in every five minutes. I am trying to use [Chime](http://vertx.io/blog/time-scheduling-with-chime/) which is a time scheduler verticle. Documentation shows how to listen to the time events and creating a scheduler with this piece of code

```
eventBus.send<JsonObject> (
    "chime",
    JsonObject {
        "operation" -> "create",
        "name" -> "my scheduler:my timer",
        "description" -> JsonObject {
            "type" -> "cron",
            "seconds" -> "0",
            "minutes" -> "30",
            "hours" -> "16",
            "days of month" -> "*",
            "months" -> "*",
            "days of week" -> "SundayL"
        }
    }
);
```

Where `*` represents any. How can I configure `eventBus` to execute the scheduler in every five minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such a simple trigger, you could use an *interval* timer:

```
{
  "type": "interval",
  "delay": "300"
};
```

The delay is a value in seconds.

Comment: what does this `"delay" : "300"` means delay in 3 milliseconds ?

Comment: what's the difference between if i write `"minutes" : "05"` or  `"delay" : "300"`  in eventBus ?

Comment: @Lokesh as explained in the response the delay is a value in **seconds**